# Copy to clipboard javascript navigator.clipboard.write

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is a color picker random generator.

On click of a button, it does not copy hex code to the clipboard.

It is giving error

> Uncaught  typeerror copyText.select is not function

Copied the text: undefined copytext[object HTMLSpanElement]

navigator​.​clipboard​.​write​Text or navigator​.​clipboard​.​write​

```js
 const hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
 const btn = document.getElementById("button");
 const color = document.querySelector(".color");
 btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let hexColor = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hexColor += hex[getRandomNumber()];
    }
    color.textContent = hexColor;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
 });

 function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
 }

 function myFunction() {
    let copyText = document.getElementById("color-code");
    console.log("copytext" + copyText);
    copyText.select();
    navigator.clipboard.write(copyText.value);
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
 }
```

```html
 <section class="hero  is-large">
     <div class="hero-body">
         <div class="container has-text-centered">
             <div class="columns is-mobile">
                 <div class="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
                     <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header field is-grouped">
                             <h3 class="card-header-title is-inline">
                                 <span> Background Color <span class="tag is-large  is-pulled-right color" id="color-code">hexcode </span>
                                 </span>
                             </h3>
                             <button class="button p-4 m-4" id="copyColorHex" onclick="myFunction()">
                                 <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-3 h-3 " fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                         <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2M9 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2" />
                                     </svg>
                                 </span>
                             </button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container has-text-centered">
             <div class="p-5 ">
                 <button class="button " id="button">click me</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) is only available on `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements. You can make an `<input readonly>` to hold the color output (in its `value` attribute, rather than the content of a `<span>`), or you can select the text of the `<span>` element using:

   ```js
   const range = new Range();
   range.selectNode(elementToSelect);
   getSelection().removeAllRanges();
   getSelection().addRange(range);
   ```
2. `value` is also only available on certain form elements. It's not defined for a `<span>` element, so it's giving the value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined). You can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the content of a `<span>`, or most other elements (but not `<input>` elements).
3. It looks like you might be mixing up clipboard copying strategies. `navigator.clipboard.write` and `writeText` don't require you to select text first. But if you're doing that as a fallback for browsers that don't support the Async Clipboard API that's fine. `writeText` is the one you want, as it takes a string, whereas `write` takes an array of `ClipboardItem`s. (`writeText` also has better browser support.)

Putting it together:

```js
const textToCopy = span.textContent;
if (navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.writeText) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy).then(function() {
        alert("Copied to clipboard:", textToCopy);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to copy to clipboard.\n\n" + error);
    });
} else {
    // fallback for older browsers
    const range = new Range();
    range.selectNode(span);
    getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    getSelection().addRange(range);
    if (document.execCommand("Copy")) {
        alert("Copied to clipboard:", textToCopy);
    } else {
        alert("Failed to copy to clipboard.");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for an hidden <input> element, `const r = new Range(); r.selectNode(elem); getSelection().addRange(r);` is probably easier to implement.

Comment: @1j01 Thanks, by removing select() as want to use span tag it gives undefined error

Comment: I updated my answer to include selecting a span's text as an option, and to note that `value` is also not defined for a span element. @Sid08 I'm not sure what you're seeing, if it's a TypeError saying the clipboard API doesn't exist, or if you're just seeing "undefined" in your alert/clipboard. If it's the latter, it's not really an "error", per se, but a value. You need to use `textContent` instead of `value`. (The value of `span.value` is `undefined`, since the property `value` is not defined for span elements.)

Comment: @1j01
Thanks, for the detailed explanation to solve the confusion about input and span

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
 const btn = document.getElementById("button");
 const color = document.querySelector(".color");
 btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let hexColor = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hexColor += hex[getRandomNumber()];
    }
    color.textContent = hexColor;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
 });

 function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
 }

 function myFunction() {
    let copyText = document.getElementById("color-code");
    
    var input = document.createElement("textarea");
    input.value = copyText.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    navigator.clipboard.write(input.value);
    alert("Copied the text: " + input.value);
       input.remove();
     }
```

```html
 <section class="hero  is-large">
     <div class="hero-body">
         <div class="container has-text-centered">
             <div class="columns is-mobile">
                 <div class="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
                     <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header field is-grouped">
                             <h3 class="card-header-title is-inline">
                                 <span> Background Color <span class="tag is-large  is-pulled-right color" id="color-code">hexcode </span>
                                 </span>
                             </h3>
                             <button class="button p-4 m-4" id="copyColorHex" onclick="myFunction()">
                                 <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    copy color
                                 </span>
                             </button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container has-text-centered">
             <div class="p-5 ">
                 <button class="button " id="button">click me</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

**Reason why the error occurred**
select will work only for the `input, textarea, select box, option, optgroup, fieldset` it won't work for `any block element and span element`, you can read more about select [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

and as per my code above, here I'm creating the `textarea` and adding the color code to that and after the `select()` called I'm removing that from the dom element

Comment: "select box, and so on" what's that?

Comment: @CodeBug Thanks for the answer  if select() is not used it give an error undefined as select only work input field